# setting up Single Tenant Application in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I registered a client and a web api service in Azure AD.  When I invoke sign in, after signing in, I am getting the following error:

Need admin approval

needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.

I went through lots of links and it is telling it is due to multi tenant.  How can I convert it to Single Tenant.  As my org is huge, and I am creating PoCs I cannot get admin approval.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you registered two applications in Azure AD, and wanted to use your client app to access web api service.

If so, you need to check the apis you exposed in your web api app. You need to allow users to consent, don't choose admin only.

[image]

> How can I convert it to Single Tenant?

1.Change the supported account type to `Accounts in this organizational directory only`.

[image]

2.update your code to handle single issuer value

Replace

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common
```

with

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your_tenant}    //contoso.onmicrosoft.com
```

Comment: how am I able to expose an API on a single-tenant app. I get this error when trying to expose an API on an existing app. Failed to update application property. Error detail: Converged application cannot be restricted to single tenant by setting 'availableToOtherTenants'.